# Diagonalization of a linear transformation in the polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, transformation, diagonalization

Let $V = R_3[X]$ be the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients of degree at most 3 and consider the linear transformation $V \rightarrow V$ defined by $f_a(p(x))=p(1-ax)$ for each $p(x) \in V$. For which values of $a$, $f_a$ is diagonalizable?

What I did:

Let be $p(x) = bx^3 + cx^2+dx+e$ a generic polynomial.

So $f_a(p(x)) = b(1-ax)^3 + c(1-ax)^2+d(1-ax)+e=…=(-a^3b)x^3+a^2(3b+c)x^2-a(3b+2c+d)x+(b+c+d+e)$

So the transformation matrix is: 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -a^3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    3a^2 & a^2 & 0 & 0 \\
    -3a & -2a & -a & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}

Finally I found the characteristic polynomial that seems to be $p(\lambda)=(a+\lambda)^2(a-\lambda)(a^3+\lambda)$
Can someone tell me if my procedure is correct? Now i have to discuss the eigenvalues found?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial should be $(\lambda-a^2)(a+\lambda)(a^3+\lambda)(\lambda-1)$. Then, yes, you have to determine when $p(\lambda)$ has four real roots.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot some $\lambda$ on the way!
So my eigenvalues are $\lambda = -a$, $\lambda = -a^3$, $\lambda = a^2$, $\lambda = -1$, that has four real roots for $\lambda \neq 0, \pm 1$. Finally I have to discuss this last 3 cases and i finished, right?

Comment: Yep. And the roots don't have to be distinct.